# Deallocation of a structure keeps crashing program

Tags: c++, memory-management

So I'm trying to deallocate memory from a vector structure.  It works fine when there's is a vector of 3 or less.  However, when it is brought up to 4 or higher, and I try calling the deallocate function, it crashes. I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing the deconstruction right and I need a hint as to where it is gone wrong here...

```
void dealloc_vec(Vector * myVector)
{


myVector->size = 0;
//Delete the array of Vectors.
delete(myVector->vectorArray);
//Finally delete the entire vector.
delete(myVector);
}
```

And my structure is this

```
struct Vector
{
unsigned int size;
Elem *vectorArray;
};
```

Elem is a float.  Whenever a greater size than 3 is created it crashes the program before exiting. We're using procedural c++ right.

```
Vector *alloc_vec(void)
{
//create a vector
Vector *temp_Vector = new Vector();

//Using getInt from above to grab values for the size of vector, if given 0 it will just be a 0 vector.
temp_Vector->size = getInt((char*)"Please enter a value: ");
/*Test to see if it is less than zero, if it is program will halt.
assert(temp_Vector->size >= 0);
No need to check as unsigned int cannot be negative according to Wtype-limits
The size of vectorArray is now initialized from the size parameter of the structure.*/
temp_Vector->vectorArray =  new float(temp_Vector->size);

//Loop through each element and assign a value from the user using getFloat (It looks cleaner         with having separate functions).
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp_Vector->size; i++)
{
    printf("Vector Element %d: ",i);
    temp_Vector->vectorArray[i] = getFloat((char*)"");
}
//return the new vector.
return temp_Vector;


}
```

getFloat and getInt

```
float getFloat(char* promptMessage)
{
assert(promptMessage != NULL);
float myInput;
char size[100];
bool sucessful = false;

do
{
    printf("%s", promptMessage);
    //Use fgets to get the input from stdin.
    fgets(size, 100, stdin);
    //Check if value is anything but zero, if it isn't use this.
    if(sscanf(size, "%f", &myInput) == 1)
    {

        myInput = atof(size);
        sucessful = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a correct number: ");
    }
}while(!sucessful);


return myInput;
}

int getInt(char* promptMessage)
{
assert(promptMessage != NULL);
int myInput;
char size[100];
bool sucessful = false;

do
{
    printf("%s", promptMessage);
    fgets(size, 100, stdin);
    //Get the size using fgets and sscanf
    sscanf(size, "%i", &myInput);

    //Size cannot be greater than 65535 or less than 0.
    if(atoi(size) > 65535)
    {
        printf("The chosen value is too large!\n");
    }
    else if(atoi(size) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error! Value is too small!\n");
    }
    //If sscanf is anything but a number, don't do this.
    else if(sscanf(size, "%i", &myInput) == 1)
    {

        myInput = atoi(size);
        sucessful = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a correct number: ");
    }
}while(!sucessful);

return myInput;
}
```

Comment: could you show the code that allocates the myVector and vectorArray ?

Comment: Use std::vector and get rid of all of your code besides Elem. (And avoid pointers(

Comment: Anyway, the code is incomplete.

Comment: @DieterLücking the point of this is to create a simple vector calculator. I'm trying to learn some C++ programming, and usage of pointers.  I'm not allowed to use vector for this.

Comment: Something is going wrong here (Am I slapping the professor or student !?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
Vector *alloc_vec(void)
{
  //create a vector
  Vector *temp_Vector = new Vector;  // don't use ()

  temp_Vector->size = getInt((char*)"Please enter a value: ");
  temp_Vector->vectorArray =  new float[temp_Vector->size];

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp_Vector->size; i++)
  {
    printf("Vector Element %d: ",i);
    temp_Vector->vectorArray[i] = getFloat((char*)"");
  }
  return temp_Vector;
}
```

then in dealloc

```
void dealloc_vec(Vector * myVector)
{
  myVector->size = 0; // there is no need for this
  //Delete the array of Vectors.
  delete [] myVector->vectorArray;  // no need for the ()
  //Finally delete the entire vector.
  delete myVector;
}
```

EDIT:

your getInt/getFloat look a bit wrong

```
sscanf(size, "%i", &myInput);
//Size cannot be greater than 65535 or less than 0.
if(atoi(size) > 65535)
```

instead simply do something like this

```
int getInt(const char* prompt) 
{ 
  int n = 0;
  char buf[32]; 
  do
  {
    printf( "%s", prompt ); 
    fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stdin ); 
    n = atoi(buf); // will ignore the \n
  }
  while ( n > 65535 );
  return n; 
}
```

for float just replace atoi with atof (and the limit if appropriate). note that atoi and atof return 0 if text is entered so you may want to check if >0

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work. Is it the initialization of getting the values or something? It seems it just crashes at random times when I enter values. It only seems when the vector is greater than four it has issues with it.

Comment: maybe you could show how your getFloat and getInt look like, i would assume something like `int getInt(const char* prompt) { char buf[32]; printf( "%s", prompt ); fgets( buf, sizeof(buf), stdin ); return atoi(buf); }`

Comment: It seems to have worked! Deallocating works in the entire program, but the only issue now lies in my automated testing.  I'm not sure why it won't work there, but it works everywhere else!

Answer (score 1):

If you allocated it by `[]` such as `new Elem [x]` then you should de-allocated it by

```
delete [] myVector->vectorArray;
```

You can use `std::vector` to make your coding easier. Or even `std::unique_ptr`

```
std::unique_ptr<Elem[]> vectorArray(new Elem[x]);
```

Comment: I didn't quite allocate the vectorArray like that. I'll post my allocate but what I did was get the size, stored it in myVector->size, then declared it by myVector->vectorArray =  new float(myVector->size);  So should I declared myVector->vectorArray = new Vector[size]?

Comment: @Phlex new float(myVector->size); will initialize with 'size' not create an array

Comment: @claptrap I'll show my code that allocates the vector in a second here!

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to your `struct` that initialises the members. `vectorArray` initially points to random memory locations and deleting those will cause undefined behaviour.

```
struct Vector
{
  Vector() : size(0), vectorArray(NULL) {}

  unsigned int size;
  Elem *vectorArray;
};
```